# Python // Filter out certain dates from an array by comparison from today's date

Tags: python, date, datetime

I have this list of dates:

```
['2020-03-17 12:00:00', '2020-03-17 15:00:00', '2020-03-17 18:00:00', '2020-03-17 21:00:00', '2020-03-18 00:00:00', '2020-03-18 03:00:00', '2020-03-18 06:00:00', '2020-03-18 09:00:00', '2020-03-18 12:00:00', '2020-03-18 15:00:00', '2020-03-18 18:00:00', '2020-03-18 21:00:00', '2020-03-19 00:00:00', '2020-03-19 03:00:00', '2020-03-19 06:00:00', '2020-03-19 09:00:00', '2020-03-19 12:00:00', '2020-03-19 15:00:00', '2020-03-19 18:00:00', '2020-03-19 21:00:00']
```

It contains times with a 3 hour gap each and several dates upto 2020-3-19, in the format of YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS.

Using date i can get today's date, and now i want to compare today's date to my list above and get all the dates that match today's current date and tommorow, **i.e: Today is 2020-03-17, i want to get all dates with their times that match today and tommorow's date, meaning 2020-03-17 and 2020-03-18**

```
from datetime import date
current_date = date.today()
```

This is for a small practice project in python for a weather api request.
(I'm new to the python, i tried researching about this issue, it's quite hard to get results and it would be best to ask it here, might be a waste of time for you guys but it helps greatly~)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define today and tomorrow's date beforehand, loop over the strings in the list, parse them appropiately using `datetime.strptime`, and see if the date part matches with either today or tomorrow's date:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

today = datetime.today().date()
tomorrow = today + timedelta(days=1)

out = []
for i in l:
    date =  datetime.strptime(i, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').date()
    if date == today or date == tomorrow:
        out.append(i)

print(out)

['2020-03-17 12:00:00',
 '2020-03-17 15:00:00',
 '2020-03-17 18:00:00',
 '2020-03-17 21:00:00',
 '2020-03-18 00:00:00',
 '2020-03-18 03:00:00',
 '2020-03-18 06:00:00',
 '2020-03-18 09:00:00',
 '2020-03-18 12:00:00',
 '2020-03-18 15:00:00',
 '2020-03-18 18:00:00',
 '2020-03-18 21:00:00']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the array and check whether the dates are current to today or tomorrow's date object:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

today = datetime.now().date()
tomorrow = today + timedelta(days=1)

dates = [datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').date() for s in strings]
result = [date for date in dates if date in (today, tomorrow)]
```

Comment: ```result = [datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') in (today, tomorrow)
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not float```

error?

Comment: @beepbeep-boop Your input data definitely seems to be strings, so I can't tell where you get a `float` object from.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dateutil.parser` helps you avoid defining/handling a fixed datetime format. It handles that automatically for you.

```
from dateutil import parser
from datetime import date, timedelta

#timestamps=[your list of datatimes]

today = date.today()
tomorrow=today + timedelta(days=1)

result=[dt for dt in timestamps if today <= parser.parse(dt).date() <= tomorrow]
```